# Finding Hamming Numbers - not code or distance

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, time-complexity, hamming-numbers

I'm currently learning C++.

I am looking for [Hamming numbers](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hamming_numbers) ([numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_number) whose prime divisors are less or equal to 5).

When I input a number *n*, the program should output the *n*-th Hamming number.

Following numbers are input, and output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 ...

1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 12 15 16 18 20 24 ...
```

Finding Hamming numbers looks easy, but increasing the input number increases run time cost exponentially.

If I input over `1000`, it almost costs over `1` second,
and over `1200`, it almost costs over `5` seconds.

This is the code I wrote:

```
while (th > 1)
{
    h++;
    x = h;

    while (x % 2 == 0)
        x /= 2;
    while (x % 3 == 0)
        x /= 3;
    while (x % 5 == 0)
        x /= 5;

    if (x == 1)
        th--;
}
```

So I would like to know how I can find the answer faster.
This algorithm doesn't seem to be very good.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this out: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hamming_numbers

Comment: Also, here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_number

Comment: You only need to do 1 division to get to a number that you've already done.  Memoize.

Comment: @stark memoizing an exponential space is not advisable.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is good if you want to check whether one particular number is a hamming number. When you want to build a list of hamming numbers, it is inefficient.

You can use a bottom-up approach: Start with 1 and then recursively multiply that with 2, 3, and 5 to get all hamming numbers up to a certain limit. You have to take care of duplicates, because you can get to 6 by way of 2·3 and 3·2. A set can take care of that.

The code below will generate all hamming numbers that fit into a 32-bit unsigned int. It fills a set by "spreading" to all hamming numbers. Then it constructs a sorted vector from the set, which you can use to find a hamming number at a certain index:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

typedef unsigned int uint;

const uint umax = 0xffffffff;

void spread(std::set<uint> &hamming, uint n)
{
    if (hamming.find(n) == hamming.end()) {
        hamming.insert(n);

        if (n < umax / 2) spread(hamming, n * 2);
        if (n < umax / 3) spread(hamming, n * 3);
        if (n < umax / 5) spread(hamming, n * 5);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::set<uint> hamming;

    spread(hamming, 1);

    std::vector<uint> ordered(hamming.begin(), hamming.end());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ordered.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << i << ' ' << ordered[i] << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code is faster than your linear method even if you end up creating more hamming numbers than you need.

You don't even need a set if you make sure that you don't construct a number twice. Every hamming number can be written as `h = 2^n2 + 3^n3 + 5^n5`, so if you find a means to iterate through these uniquely, you're done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

typedef unsigned int uint;

int main()
{
    const uint umax = 0xffffffff;
    std::vector<uint> hamming;

    for (uint k = 1;; k *= 2) {
        for (uint l = k;; l *= 3) {
            for (uint m = l;; m *= 5) {
                hamming.push_back(m);
                if (m > umax / 5) break;
            }
            if (l > umax / 3) break;
        }
        if (k > umax / 2) break;
    }

    std::sort(hamming.begin(), hamming.end());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < hamming.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << i << ' ' << hamming[i] << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The strange `break` syntax for the loops is required, because we have to check the size before the overflow. If `umax*5` were guananteed not to overflow, these conditions could be written in the condition part of the loop.

The code examples in [the Rosetta Code link](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hamming_numbers) [Koshinae](https://stackoverflow.com/users/357403/koshinae) [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29286845/finding-hamming-numbers-not-code-or-distance#comment46771689_29286845) use similar strategies, but I'm surprised how lengthy some of them are.

Answer (score 0):

In this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ugly-numbers/) you can find two different solutions for finding the *nth* hamming number. The second method is the optimized one which can get the result in a few seconds.

```
/* Function to get the nth ugly number*/
unsigned getNthUglyNo(unsigned n) 
{ 
    unsigned ugly[n]; // To store ugly numbers 
    unsigned i2 = 0, i3 = 0, i5 = 0; 
    unsigned next_multiple_of_2 = 2; 
    unsigned next_multiple_of_3 = 3; 
    unsigned next_multiple_of_5 = 5; 
    unsigned next_ugly_no = 1; 

    ugly[0] = 1; 
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++) 
    { 
        next_ugly_no = min(next_multiple_of_2, 
                           min(next_multiple_of_3, 
                               next_multiple_of_5)); 
        ugly[i] = next_ugly_no; 
        if (next_ugly_no == next_multiple_of_2) 
        { 
            i2 = i2+1; 
            next_multiple_of_2 = ugly[i2]*2; 
        } 
        if (next_ugly_no == next_multiple_of_3) 
        { 
            i3 = i3+1; 
            next_multiple_of_3 = ugly[i3]*3; 
        } 
        if (next_ugly_no == next_multiple_of_5) 
        { 
           i5 = i5+1; 
           next_multiple_of_5 = ugly[i5]*5; 
        } 
    } /*End of for loop (i=1; i<n; i++) */

return next_ugly_no; 
}
```